# disable function using javascript

Tags: javascript

I can not seem to find the code to disable a javascript function. What I want to do is have a javascript function and then I want to disable it. Here is the code:

```
 <script>
 var fooFunc = function fooFunction() {
      alert("HELLO");
 };

 $(document).ready(function() {
      fooFunc.disable();    
 });
 </script>

 <button onclick="fooFunc()">Button</button>
```

Basically, when the button is click the function should not work, it should be disabled. Thanks

Comment: There's no disable, you have to work around that

Comment: I think it was null...

Comment: If you null it, how do you enable it when he wants to?

Comment: That is a good question.... yea how? I have the code on one of my websites.... but I can not seem to find it.

Comment: I think @David's answer below should do it.

Comment: I think it might be the same code anyways...

Comment: I don't understand. If you don't want the button to call `fooFunc()` when pressed, then why specify `onclick` in the first place?

Answer (score 2):

"Disabling" `fooFunc` is the same as setting it to an empty function (**not** to `null`--that will cause an error when it is called the next time). In this case:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  fooFunc = function() { };
});
```

But I don't see how this is different from simply removing the `onclick` handler from the HTML element.

If you want the ability to disable/re-enable the function, you can write it like this:

```
fooFunc = function() {

  function _fooFunc() {
    if (!enabled) return;
    alert("HELLO");
  }

  var enabled = true;
  _fooFunc.enable  = function() { enabled = true; };
  _fooFunc.disable = function() { enabled = false; };

  return _fooFunc;

}();
```

If you want to extend this to allow any function to be enabled/disabled, you can write a higher-order function, which takes any function as a parameter, and returns a function with `enable` and `disable` methods attached to it:

```
function disablable(fn) {

  function inner() {
    if (!enabled) return;
    fn();
  }

  var enabled = true;

  inner.enable  = function() { enabled = true; };
  inner.disable = function() { enabled = false; };

  return inner;

}
```

Now you can define `fooFunc` as

```
var fooFunc = disablable(function fooFunction() {
  alert("HELLO");
});
```

and the rest of your code will work as you want.

Comment: I like your solution, pretty creative.

Answer (score 1):

You can access the onclick property of the element..

```
 <button id="id" onclick="fooFunc()">Button</button>


 <script>
   document.querySelector('#id').onclick = '';
 </script>
```

Comment: just because i think..way this site is going :(

Comment: I'd really like to understand, is what is suggested here possible?

Comment: Personally I prefer to set it to null. But empty string works too

Comment: @ahitt6345 No, no-one can change `null`.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want the function to work at all and be totally disabled then use the below.

If you want the function to work only under certain conditions then you will need `if/else` statements so it will work only when the conditions that you have set are met.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").onclick(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Comment: I don't think this is going to do what you think or what the OP wants.

Answer (score 0):

You were going to define it back to undefined or null.

```
fooFunc=undefined;
```

Comment: Technically, this answer is right, it's just not the best way.

Comment: Exactly, but the function won't be able to be called, doing exactly what the user wants. Technically.

Comment: setting the function to a function to an empty string will result in an error as well.

Comment: @ahitt6345 I doubt if what the user wants is a JS run-time error which will stop his or her program.

Comment: I was being technical/sarcastic.

Answer (score 0):

You Should be doing this :) Change function definition on very first run and you are good to go.

```
<! DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">


<body>
<script>
    var fooFunc = function() {
        alert("HELLO");
        fooFunc = function(){};
    };

    var enablefooFunc = function()
    {
        fooFunc = function() {
            alert("HELLO");
            fooFunc = function(){};
        };
    }

</script>

<button onclick="fooFunc()">Run once and Disable FooFunc</button>
<button onclick="enablefooFunc()">Enable FooFunc</button>
</body>

</html>
```